# Why is var $importantVar allowed where as other special characters are not allowed as first letter?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Valid Characters for JavaScript Variable Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names)

Started learning Javascript and found out that one can name a variable like

`var $importantVar;`

I am wondering can we name variables with a `$` sign while all other special characters are not allowed?

Note: I know you can use _ too before the name but thats something which is allowed in all other languages too(At least C and C++).

Comment: You can name it `_importantVar` too.

Comment: You can also use the underscore `var _`

Comment: this blog explains everything about javascript variables. take a look: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers

Comment: @FahadUddin Its dollar diplomacy :)

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names